# Julia: Index an array with Int64?

Tags: julia

The following code complains

```
ERROR: `setindex!` has no method matching setindex!(::Type{Array{Int32,32}}, ::Int32, ::Int64)
```

Should I be able to do this? The problem, I think, is that the loop variable has the wrong type to be used as an array index?

```
n = parseint(readline(STDIN))
A = Array{Int32, n}
for i in 1:n-1
    ai = parseint(Int32, readuntil(STDIN, ' '))
    A[i] = ai #The error happens here!
end
A[n] = parseint(Int32, readline(STDIN))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assignment of **A** is legal, but it doesn't do what you think it does.

```
A = Array{Int32,n}

julia> typeof(A)
DataType
```

This declares an **A** to be the type representing an array of n dimensions. What you want instead, probably is **A** to be a variable of type *Array{Int32,1}* that contains **n** elements.  So instead try the following:

```
A = Array(Int32,n);

julia> typeof(A)
Array{Int32,1}
```